# CSS filter inherit issue: Solution without pseudo element for dynamic sized divs?

Tags: html, css, css-filters

I've been trying to solve the following issue for a while now, but wasn't able to come up with a working solution.

**What I want to achieve:**

*Resting state:* having a background image desaturated and overlayed with a semi transparent, colored div.

*Hover stage:* saturating the image, changing color of the overlay

Obviously we're diving into the problem of inheriting CSS filters to the children. I have to add one technical restriction, which made it impossible so far for me: **The background image can't be applied to a pseudo element like `:before`**. Reason for that being: it is injected inline with php in the final application. À la: `<div class="background-image"<?php ... ?>">`

**[Here's the current stadium in a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/h5zM3/)**

Current problem: overlay is being greyscaled, because the parent is being grayscaled. As mentioned I tried different approaches, always ending up in a similar problem. Feels like going in circles. Anyone having an idea?

Comment: Can you construct a fiddle that matches the restriction you've described? This will make it less likely for someone to create a solution that oversteps this restriction.

Comment: Good point @BoltClock, I updated the fiddle accordingly. Not using PHP obviously, but I think it still makes a point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Old Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5zM3/6/)**

Like you said, the issue here is the grayscale filter. By moving the filter and background image to the `.post-preview` div, it allows you to set the `.post-preview-wrapper` to `background-color: red` and get the red overlay effect with an `opaticy` toggle. I think this should work with your restriction since it's targeting elements you're already working with.

**-Update-**

You're right, since opacity effects all children the text ended up faded too. If you can't use a `before` class, it means you'll have to alter the HTML a bit. Moving the background to a different element allowed it to not effect the `h1`. Then you just need to position the `h1` over the background image.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/h5zM3/8/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="post-preview-wrapper">
    <div class="post-preview">
         <div class="post-preview-bg"></div>
         <h1><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-preview-wrapper {
    // current styles

    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.post-preview > h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 75px;
}

.post-preview-wrapper:hover .post-preview-bg {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.post-preview-bg {
    opacity: .75;
    height: 210px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-7.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
    transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @badAdviceGuy. Problem with this is, that the opacity is being inherited to the text. So the text can't be 100% white in the resting state. Right? That's exactly my "going in circles" issue...

Comment: @psteinweber, good point on the text opacity. I didn't catch that. See my edits in my answer, they may work for you.